# How to plot two sets of data in python

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, plot

There are two sets of data in two lists. The lists are **x=[1,2,3,...,1000]** and **y=[0.12,0.59,-0.89,...,0.45]**.

I want to plot them in xy coordinate. I searched on the net and I figured out that I should download matplotlib and Anaconda which I did. But due to the fact that I am a new python user, I could not figure out how to plot it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x =[1,2,3,10]
y =[0.12,0.59,-0.89,0.45]

plt.plot(x, y, 'o-')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately when I write import matplotlib.pyplot as plt in python shell, I get an error. I have installed the matplotlib and Anaconda but I do not know what is problem. I am a new python user so please bear me.

Comment: That's odd.  Are you sure that you're using the right python?  When I start the python shell the first line is something like "Python 2.7.6 |Anaconda 1.9.0 (x86_64)".  Does yours also say "Anaconda"?  Also, what exactly is the error you get?

Comment: When I start Python Shell the first line is: Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:24:47) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32. Can you help me to fix this?

Comment: This is the problem.  If after spending a few minutes seeing if you can figure out how to run the Anaconda version you can't figure it out, it would be better to ask a separate question.  Be sure to list all of the relevant information, like the OS, where Anaconda is installed to, etc.

Comment: See: http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/faq.html#open-packages Also, just a quick idea: instead of typing "python" at the command line, try "ipython".  Also, doesn't anaconda install a bunch of launchers when you go to "Program Files", and can you launch get it started from there?  (I'm on a mac, so and I don't have a windows machine with anaconda installed.)